# Resulset esta demasiado lento

Tags: java, mysql

Tengo una tabla de una base de datos con tres registro y el `Resulset` se demora demasiado en cargar, es decir el método `executeQuery()`, acá les dejo el código:

```
 System.out.println("antes de la consultapreparada");//aqui
 PreparedStatement consultaPreparada=conexion.prepareStatement("SELECT * FROM productos");
 System.out.println("antes de llenar el resultset");//aqui 
 ResultSet resultado=consultaPreparada.executeQuery();
```

Tambien les dejo una imagen de la tabla de la base de datos:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Creo que el problema es de la tabla.
Tengo otra tabla en la misma base de datos que se lee super rápido.

Comment: Te recomiendo que leas [*Using Large Objects*](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/basics/blob.html#add_retrieve_blob) en los tutoriales de Java. Allí se explica el modo correcto de recuperar datos del tipo Blob. El ejemplo de código es sobre un dato del tipo `Clob`, pero lo cambias por `Blob` y usas el método `getBlob` y todo lo demás es igual. Haciendo eso debería ir más rápido, tampoco tus datos son demasiado grandes, no hay motivos para que vaya lento si manejas bien los datos, a no ser que haya otra parte del código que ralentice el funcionamiento.

Comment: muchas gracias. Otra pregunta por favor. ¿la coneccion con la base de datos suele demorar menos de 1 segundo? mi coneccion demora como 4 segundos aproximadamente, ¿es eso normal?

Comment: Debes revisar si tienes todo actualizado: versión de JDBC, versión de la base de datos, versión de Java, etc. Si es una base de datos local no debería haber motivo para que tarde, otra cosa que puede ralentizar sería que tengas antivirus o firewall que bloqueen los puertos que usa la base de datos.

Comment: libere el puerto de entrada de firewall y desactive el antivirus y nada, es raro.

Comment: ¿Tienes todo al día? Y 4 segundos para conectar tampoco es tanto ¿no? A no ser que tengas un equipo de la NASA que trabaje tan lentamente.

Comment: jajajajaja es que en todos los videos que veo demoran menos de un segundo en conectar jejejejejejeje

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No es aconsejable almacenar imágenes en una base de datos, es mejor guardar esas imágenes en un directorio y colocar solamente la ruta a ese archivo en la base de datos. Quizás de ahí tu lentitud al obtener los datos de la consulta.

Comment: Tienes razon, pero el asunto es que quiero guardar remotamente imagenes en la base de datos, con el metodo que tu mencionas sirve solo para leer imagenes remotamente desde una base de datos(parece)